# Access to path 'D:\\ocean.gif' is denied

Tags: silverlight-5.0

In my Silverlight application I am getting this error:

> File operation not permitted. Access to path 'D:\ocean.gif' is denied.

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Try storing the image in `my documents` folder.

Answer (score 2):

By default, you are not allowed to access the local file system from a Silverlight application; only the [isolated file storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is available for standard Silverlight applications.

You may configure your Silverlight application to use [elevated trust](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721083%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). This will give your SL application full access to the local file system. This is normally most practical for out-of-browser applications; there are many [deployment restrictions](http://www.pitorque.de/MisterGoodcat/post/Silverlight-5-Tidbits-Trusted-applications.aspx) associated with in-browser elevated-trust applications.

**UPDATE** Another alternative that normally do not require you to set elevated-trust is to read the image as a [FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) using the [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.openfiledialog%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

```
var dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
if (dlg.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault())
{
    var stream = dlg.File.OpenRead();

    ... read the stream using a suitable image reader class ...
}
```

Right out of my head I cannot point out sufficient image stream readers that work in Silverlight, but try Googling for it.

To use elevated-trust in your applications, simply enable elevated-trust in your project. This is described in detail in the MSDN documentation.

Comment: Thanks Anders. but if possible could you please provide me sample project on this?

Comment: :-please provide me some sample project on this?

Comment: and without using  OpenfileDialog how can we achive this ?

Comment: Then elevated trust is your only choice. But please consult the MSDN documentation to learn how to configure this.